# Which of these two sql joins will perform better?

Tags: sql, join

I've always been curious of which method of SQL joining I should be using.  The following two queries perform exactly the same function, which of the two is better?

```
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, o.OrderNo
FROM Persons p
INNER JOIN Orders o
ON p.P_Id = o.P_Id

SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, o.OrderNo
FROM Persons p, Orders o
WHERE p.P_Id = o.P_Id
```

In summary, does using the words INNER JOIN actually perform better than 'WHERE x = y' ?

Comment: No they will have the same execution plan in any sensible RDBMS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a JOIN faster than a WHERE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129923/is-a-join-faster-than-a-where)

Comment: You can easily find that out yourself by running them and looking at the execution plan (I'm actually tempted to downvote the question because of that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 is the ANSI standard version that is used in sql server while Case 2 was the syntax that was used earlier and is depreciated. [Go through this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

```
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, o.OrderNo FROM Persons p INNER JOIN Orders o ON p.P_Id = o.P_Id  

SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, o.OrderNo FROM Persons p, Orders o WHERE p.P_Id = o.P_Id
```

Hence performance of both the query will be same

Please note there if your query had been little different. i.e.

```
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, o.OrderNo FROM Persons p LEFT JOIN Orders o ON p.P_Id = o.P_Id AND p.Id = 1
```

Vs

```
 SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, o.OrderNo FROM Persons p LEFT JOIN Orders o ON p.P_Id = o.P_Id WHERE p.Id = 1
```

In this case query will work completely different. Output of both the queries will be different.

For understanding this...[See this](http://techpint.com/programming/how-sql-joins-works)

Answer (score 1):

It doens't matter. The good DBMS optimises it to the same code, essentially making them the same.