# Hanging mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having an issue with the following query

```
select
ord.order_id, 
ordProduct.product_id,
coupProd.product_id,
coup.date_end as DateEnd, coup.coupon_id
from `order` ord
inner join order_product ordProduct on ord.order_id = ordProduct.order_id
inner join coupon_product coupProd on ordProduct.product_id = coupProd.product_id
inner join coupon coup on coupProd.coupon_id = coup.coupon_id
where (coup.date_end > curdate());
```

If I remvove the where clause, the query executes fine, otherwise it just hangs.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does it speed it up moving the where clause to the inner join?  
inner join coupon coup on coupProd.coupon_id = coup.coupon_id AND (coup.date_end > curdate());

Comment: just how many records are involved here?

Comment: What is difference in where clause and using AND condition. Just out of curiosity

Comment: This explains the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311096/whats-the-difference-between-where-clause-and-on-clause-when-table-left-join  Not sure if it would fix the issue in this case though.

Comment: @AshReva: `WHERE` is for specifying a condition for filtering while `AND` is for filtering based on more than one conditional ("grouping" conditionals).

Comment: I think it may just be due to the sheer number of records, 30k in the order_product and coupon product table, 65k in the coupon table.  I'm only running locally, so maybe i'll let it spin for 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution per se, but as a workaround, you could maybe get it done as a nested query. i.e. ,

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    ord.order_id, 
    ordProduct.product_id,
    coupProd.product_id,
    coup.date_end AS DateEnd, coup.coupon_id
    FROM `order` ord
    INNER JOIN order_product ordProduct ON ord.order_id = ordProduct.order_id
    INNER JOIN coupon_product coupProd ON ordProduct.product_id = coupProd.product_id
    INNER JOIN coupon coup ON coupProd.coupon_id = coup.coupon_id)
WHERE (DateEnd > CURDATE());
```