# What is difference between JOIN and a.ID=b.ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have always been using JOINS but today I saw a simple code that was like that:

```
SELECT Name FROM customers c, orders d WHERE c.ID=d.ID
```

It is just the old way?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311096/whats-the-difference-between-where-clause-and-on-clause-when-table-left-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, the execution plan will be the same using that method or `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

These 2 queries are semantically identical.  With an join, predicates can be specified in either the JOIN or WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 0):

When doing just inner joins, there isn't much difference between the implicit style and ANSI joins.  Likely, there is no difference as the database will execute them the same.

But it can quickly get complex, at least when you are allowed to do implicit outer joins.  There is a few things that joins can do that you cannot do the old way.  I believe the following statement cannot be expressed with implicit joins (taken from the below link).

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
ON (T1.SOME_VALUE = 11 and T1.ID = T2.ID)
WHERE T1.OTEHR_VALUE > 3;
```

Read [this](http://optimizermagic.blogspot.com/2007/12/outerjoins-in-oracle.html) for more info.

> There appears to be some confusion about equivalence between ANSI outer join and Oracle outer join syntaxes. The following examples explain the equivalences and inequivalences of these two syntaxes.