# Lambda Expression equivalent of "<>" in from clause of SQL with Join

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda, sql-to-linq-conversion

Can anyone help me? I am not able to convert the following expression in the SQL to equivalent Lambda expression,

```
ON nextT.TaskID = a.NextTaskID AND a.TaskID <> nextT.TaskID
```

**SQL to be converted**

```
SELECT a.*
FROM            dbo.Action AS a INNER JOIN dbo.Task AS t 
ON t .TaskID = a.TaskID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Task AS nextT 
ON nextT.TaskID = a.NextTaskID AND a.TaskID <> nextT.TaskID //This need to converted
```

My incomplete attempt to convert expression is as follows

**Equivalent Lambda Expression**

```
    var context = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var data = (from a in context.Actions
                join t in context.Tasks on a.TaskID equals t.TaskID
                join nextT in context.Tasks 
on 
.......new {v1 = a.NextTaskID, v2 = a.TaskID} equals new {v1 = nextT.TaskID , v2 = nextT.TaskID}.....<---This is the problem.
                select new vw_NextTask1
                {
                    TaskID = a.TaskID,
                    Task = t.Title,
                    ActionID = a.ActionID,
                    Action = a.Title,
                    NextPhaseID = a.NextPhaseID,
                    NextTaskID = nextT.TaskID,
                    NextTask = nextT.Title,
                          Type = a.Type
                }).ToList<vw_NextTask1>();
    return data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a where clause.

```
var data = (from a in context.Actions
        join t in context.Tasks on a.TaskID equals t.TaskID
        join nextT in context.Tasks
        where nextT.TaskID != a.TaskID
```

Comment: can we remove all the checks with ON and make all the checks in the where clause. Are these both ways equivalent?

Comment: There is a difference b/w condition in Where clause and On clause  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311096/whats-the-difference-between-where-clause-and-on-clause-when-table-left-join