# outer join -- restriction on From clause

Tags: sql, outer-join

I am new to SQL. The problem I am having is I try to logically understand that restriction on From clause when I use LEFT JOIN, I have learned restriction on where clause, but I have never seen this before.  I read this article,[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311096/whats-the-difference-between-where-clause-and-on-clause-when-table-left-join#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311096/whats-the-difference-between-where-clause-and-on-clause-when-table-left-join#_=_)
 but I am still confused.

so my code is this.

```
Select e.last_name
      ,e.first_name
      ,e.marital_status_code
      ,ms.short_desc
from entity e
left join marital_status ms 
     on e.marital_status_code = ms.marital_status_code AND ms.marital_status_code = 'M'
where e.last_name = 'Hello'
order by 3
;
```

I totally understood when I put restriction on Where clause

like

```
where e.last_name = 'Hello'
AND marital_status_code = 'M'
 order by 3
    ;
```

please help me what is going on/how the logic works when I put restriction on From clause like this

```
left join marital_status ms 
         on e.marital_status_code = ms.marital_status_code AND ms.marital_status_code = 'M'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
left join marital_status ms 
     on e.marital_status_code = ms.marital_status_code AND ms.marital_status_code = 'M'
```

This is a condition on the join.

That is a restriction on when to match two row.  So this will find a match in the other table when both tables have the same marital_status_code and when marital_status_code is = 'M'in the marital_table.

This **IS THE SAME** as not having the join and saying

```
WHERE e.marital_status_code = 'M'
```

if there is a just one row in the marital_status table with a marital_status_code of 'M'

Or it **IS THE SAME** as doing nothing if there is no such row in the marital_status table.